# How to print out options used when reading CSV files in Azure Databricks

Tags: dataframe, csv, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a notebook in Azure Databricks to ingest CSV files to Bronze tables:

```
source_query = (
    spark.readStream
    .format("cloudFiles")
    .option("cloudFiles.format", "csv")   
    .option("cloudFiles.includeExistingFiles", True) 
    .option("mode","FAILFAST") 
    .option("cloudFiles.allowOverwrites", True) 
    .option("enforceSchema", "false") 
    .option("ignoreMissingFiles", True) 
    .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", checkpoint_path)
    .option("rescuedDataColumn","ctl_rescued_data") # Rescued data
    .option("skipRows", 0)
    .option("header", True) 
    .option("recursiveFileLookup", True)
)

result_df=(
    source_query.load(input_path)
    .withColumn('ctl_original_filename',input_file_name())
    .withColumn('ctl_ingestion_timestamp',lit(current_timestamp))
    .withColumn('ctl_ingestion_date',to_date(col('ctl_ingestion_timestamp')))
)
```

There are many options set in the above code and also some of the options can be overwritten later in the code.

Is there any command that I can print all options used in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

@Mohammad

guess you can loop through them using source_query.options.items() and print them out. like this see below for ref code

```html
# Print out the options used in source_query
for key, value in source_query.options.items():
    print(f"{key}: {value}")

# Now you can load your data using these options
result_df = (
    source_query.load(input_path)
    .withColumn('ctl_original_filename', input_file_name())
    .withColumn('ctl_ingestion_timestamp', lit(current_timestamp))
    .withColumn('ctl_ingestion_date', to_date(col('ctl_ingestion_timestamp')))
)
```

This should give you a friendly list of all the options and their values,

Updated  code bel;ow

```html
# Define the source_query function
def create_source_query():
    return (
        spark.readStream
        .format("cloudFiles")
        .option("cloudFiles.format", "csv")   
        .option("cloudFiles.includeExistingFiles", True) 
        .option("mode", "FAILFAST") 
        .option("cloudFiles.allowOverwrites", True) 
        .option("enforceSchema", "false") 
        .option("ignoreMissingFiles", True) 
        .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", checkpoint_path)
        .option("rescuedDataColumn", "ctl_rescued_data") # Rescued data
        .option("skipRows", 0)
        .option("header", True) 
        .option("recursiveFileLookup", True)
    )

# Call the function to get the source_query
source_query = create_source_query()

# Print out the options used in source_query
for key, value in source_query.optionItems():
    print(f"{key}: {value}")

# Now you can load your data using these options
result_df = (
    source_query.load(input_path)
    .withColumn('ctl_original_filename', input_file_name())
    .withColumn('ctl_ingestion_timestamp', lit(current_timestamp))
    .withColumn('ctl_ingestion_date', to_date(col('ctl_ingestion_timestamp')))
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I get this error: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: hey agin, i will paste the updated code again in the answer try it once